# Coinbase error for php SDK: you have not filled out your merchant profile

Tags: php, bitcoin, coinbase-api

I am trying to use the Coinbase API for bitcoin but when using the php SDK for coinbase to connect to the API I get the following error:

> "validation_error","message":"You have not filled out your merchant profile. Please enter your informat (truncated...)

I have filled all the profile fields and I am not sure what profile it is trying to indicate. Please help.

Thank you

Comment: ....looks like a pretty good question for the Coinbase support....

Comment: @NicoHaase Do you think this error might be because of country not available for tranasaction with coinbase??

Comment: I don't have any clue, but if an API returns such a message, the maintainers of the API know best why this error is given ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Coinbase has not yet approved your Merchant account - contact Coinbase support, but is really slow, I waiting from 3 days.